# recv() blocked after first reception unless a message is sent through the socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

My server code goes like:

```
while True:
    print("waiting msg from client")
    data += new_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    data = sm.run(robot, data)
      
    if not data:
        print("Robot disconnected ", robot)
        return
```

On execution, after the first input the rest will be ignored and the socket(which is blocked at recv call) ends up being closed by timeout.

This doesn't happen if server sends a message after receiving one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the client has sent another message? Maybe the client is waiting for a response from the server.

Comment: It's very confusing that you use the same variable `data` for the data received from the socket and the result of `sm.run()`. You're going to concatenate the next socket message to that result.

Comment: REMEMBER that TCP is a streaming protocol, not a packet protocol.  You don't receive exactly the same packages that were sent.  If the client sends two messages quickly, they will be combined, and you'll get BOTH in that first `recv`.  As a TCP server, you must be able to handle that.